# Find the maximum length of contagious subarray with repeated element using recursive method with only list as the parameter

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

Problem:
Find the maximum length of contagious subarray with repeated elements.
eg: 
`[1 2 2 2 3 3 5 1 8]` - answer is 3 since 2 repeated 3 times is the max repeated times.
`[1 2]` - answer is 1
`[1 2 2 3 3]` - answer is 2

But the recursive function should only have list as the argument. 
`int findMaxContagiousRepeatedLength(List<Integer> list)`

What I've tried:

```
class Answer
{
    public static int findMaxContagiousRepeatedLength(List<Integer> nums, int currentCount, int latestNumber)
    {
        if (nums.isEmpty())
            return 0;

        if (nums.get(0) == latestNumber) {
            return Math.max(currentCount+1, findMaxContagiousRepeatedLength(nums.subList(1, nums.size()), currentCount+1, nums.get(0)));
        } else {
            return findMaxContagiousRepeatedLength(nums.subList(1, nums.size()), 1, nums.get(0));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Integer[] nums = { 1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,2,3,1,2,2};

        System.out.println("Max length: " +
                findMaxContagiousRepeatedLength(Arrays.asList(nums), 0, nums.length == 0 ? -1 : nums[0]));
    }
}
```

The above does work, but doesn't meet the requirement of argument restriction.
Please help me figure out if it's possible to have a solution where recursive function only have list as the argument.

Comment: You should try [sliding window](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/window-sliding-technique/)

Comment: [Contagious](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contagious_disease)?

Answer (score 1):

Best solution

Use your Function

```
public static int findMaxContagiousRepeatedLength(List<Integer> nums, int currentCount, int latestNumber)
{
    if (nums.isEmpty())
        return 0;

    if (nums.get(0) == latestNumber) {
        return Math.max(currentCount+1, findMaxContagiousRepeatedLength(nums.subList(1, nums.size()), currentCount+1, nums.get(0)));
    } else {
        return findMaxContagiousRepeatedLength(nums.subList(1, nums.size()), 1, nums.get(0));
    }
}
```

and make a second Function which calls your function with default parameters

```
public static int findMaxContagiousRepeatedLength(List<Integer> nums)
{
    return findMaxContagiousRepeatedLength(Arrays.asList(nums), 0, nums.length == 0 ? -1 : nums[0]);
}
```

Now you can call the second function which calls the first function with default parameters!

Comment: You are using overloading, that's not OP wants I believe.

Answer (score 0):

First, this problem is best solved by just going through the list.
But if you must use recursion with `List<Integer>` as the only parameter you may use the below:

```
   public static int findMaxContiguousRepeatedLength(List<Integer> nums) {
        if (nums.isEmpty()) {
           return 0;
        }
        Iterator<Integer> it = nums.iterator();
        Integer start = it.next();
        int len = 1, pos = 1;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
           Integer curr = it.next();
           if (curr == start) {
               pos++;
               len++;
           } else {
               break;
           }
        }
        return Math.max(len,  findMaxContiguousRepeatedLength(nums.subList(pos,nums.size())));
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to (temporarily) modify the list, the below approach would also work:

```
public static int findMaxContiguousRepeatedLength(List<Integer> nums) {
    if (nums.isEmpty()) {
        return 0;
    }

    // carve out repeated chunk from back
    Integer back = nums.remove(nums.size() - 1);
    int repeats = 1;
    while(!nums.isEmpty() && nums.get(nums.size() - 1) == back) {
        nums.remove(nums.size() - 1);
        repeats++;
    }

    int res = Math.max(repeats, findMaxContiguousRepeatedLength(List<Integer> nums));
    while(repeats) { // restore
        repeats--;
        nums.add(back);
    }

    return res;   
}
```